# How can I convert int to time using datetime

Tags: python

I have a list in this format:

```
L = [445, 650, 920, 1130, 1340]
```

results would be:

```
['4:45', '6:50', '9:20', '13:40']
```

I have tried this:

```
length = len(L)
L1 = str(L)
for i in range(length):
    tm = datetime.strptime(L1[i], '%H%M').time()
    print(tm)
```

Comment: `%H`  expects a zero-padded hour. Try `tm = datetime.strptime(L1[i].zfill(4), '%H%M').time()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with time class in datetime module. Use method strftime to convert time data into any str format that you want.

```
from datetime import time


def time_int_to_str(time_int):
    hour, minute = divmod(time_int, 100)
    t = time(hour=hour, minute=minute)
    time_str = t.strftime("%H:%M")
    return time_str[1:] if time_str[0] == "0" else time_str  # get rid of 0 at the start (e.g. 01:00 -> 1:00, and protection in case of 00:00)
```

With examples you have proivided:

```
L = [445, 650, 920, 1130, 1340]
[time_int_to_str(example) for example in L]
```

We receive:

```
['4:45', '6:50', '9:20', '11:30', '13:40']
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete. OP want an array.

Comment: you can also consider using list comphrension ; i have posetd a solution above

Answer (score 2):

That input is a bit odd, are you sure it's not *decimal time* e.g. `450` is 450mn (7h30), or 4.45h aka 4h27?

If you're sure the input is described properly, then you can just use `divmod(n, 100)` to split your time in two (the integral part from a division by 100, and the rest), then put the two values in the relevant field of a `time` or `timedelta`:

```py
L = [445, 650, 920, 1130, 1340]
for v in L:
    h, m = divmod(v, 100)
    print(datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m))
```

```
04:45:00
06:50:00
09:20:00
11:30:00
13:40:00
```

It doesn't make sense as a datetime, a datetime [must have the *date* part filled completely](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), although you could [combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) the time with a reference `date` to get a `datetime`.

Comment: In my data set, I have arrival times of flight in this particular format (445 which means 4h45m)

Comment: Then you can use the convertion method I provided, using divmod to separate the hours from the minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
get_time = lambda time: str(time)[:-2] + ':' + str(time)[-2:]
list(map(get_time,L))
```

---

```
['4:45', '6:50', '9:20', '11:30', '13:40']
```

---

```
from datetime import datetime
get_time = lambda time: datetime.strptime(str(time)[:-2] + ':' + str(time)[-2:], '%H:%M').time()
res = list(map(get_time,L))
res
```

---

```
[datetime.time(4, 45),
 datetime.time(6, 50),
 datetime.time(9, 20),
 datetime.time(11, 30),
 datetime.time(13, 40)]
```

Answer (score 0):

comprehension

```
[ str(item)[:len(str(item)) - 2] + ':' + str(item)[len(str(item)) - 2:] for item in L  ]
```

['4:45', '6:50', '9:20', '11:30', '13:40']